# how the toggle function work in angular?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, jasmine, karma-runner, karma-jasmine

I make a service like that .

```
(function(){
  'use strict';
  angular.module('desert').service('desertmanager',desertmanager);

  function desertmanager(){
    this.mode='pie';
    this.setMode=function(val){
      this.mode=val;
    }

    this.getMode=function(){
      return this.mode;
    }

  }
})();
```

used that service in my controller like that ...

```
(function(){
  'use strict';
  angular.module('app.home').controller('homeCntrl',homeCntrl);
  homeCntrl.$inject=['desertmanager'];

  function homeCntrl(desertmanager){
    //alert(desertmanager.getMode());
    var home=this;
    home.clickbtn=function(){

      home.message='test';
      alert(home.message)
    }

    home.toggle=function(){
      if(desertmanager.getMode()=='pie'){
        desertmanager.setMode('cake')
      }else{
        desertmanager.setMode('yellow')
      }
    }
  }
})();
```

Now I need to test my toggle function .
I do like that as below.But I am getting error this

```
describe('toggle mode ',function(){
    var modeSpy;
    beforeEach(function(){
      modeSpy=spyOn(desertmanager,'getMode').andReturn('pie');
    })

    it('called',function(){
      controller.toggle();
      expect(modeSpy).toHaveBeenCalledWith('cake');  

    })
  })
```

I am getting this error

**TypeError: spyOn(...).andReturn is not a function**

how to test my toggle function ? how to remove this error?

here is my code
http://plnkr.co/edit/GAdTPFfl9LGXTczCG1KL?p=preview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First mistake: you're using Jasmine 2, and `andReturn()` doesn't exist in Jasmine 2. [The correct syntax](http://jasmine.github.io/2.0/introduction.html#section-Spies:_%3Ccode%3Eand.returnValue%3C/code%3E) is `and.returnValue()`.

Second mistake: you're not spying on `setMode()`, although you want to check that it has been called.

Here is a fixed version of your plunkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/JizWQijbH8FkCAI6jzpM?p=preview.

```
describe('toggle mode ',function(){
    beforeEach(function(){
      spyOn(desertmanager,'getMode').and.returnValue('pie');
      spyOn(desertmanager, 'setMode');
    });

    it('called',function(){
      controller.toggle();
      expect(desertmanager.setMode).toHaveBeenCalledWith('cake');  
    });
});
```

Comment: what is latest version ? I saw latest version is 2.4 ? is andReturn method in 2.4 ? can we change code to 2.4 version istead of 2